# If the trackpad button is clicked instead of a mouse, will MouseInputListener be triggered?

Tags: java, trackpad

I am developing an application which requires user input. So far, I have the keyboard controls set up, but I need mouse click events. My UI class implements `MouseInputListener`. My question: **if the trackpad button is clicked/moved rather than on a mouse, will the mouse events still be triggered?** If not, how would I include the trackpad's input?

Comment: Don't have a laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT will. For the JVM, a trackpad and a mouse are basically the same thing.

However, there is some unexpected behavior. For example, [scrolling is sometimes interpreted as a click.](https://superuser.com/questions/328616/two-finger-scroll-registering-as-click-event-with-java-apps-on-macbook-2-1-runni)